# NServiceBus 2.0.0.1219 not picking up messages

Tags: .net-4.0, nservicebus

After upgrading from NServiceBus 2.0.0.1145 (.net 3.5) to version 2.0.0.1219 (.net 4.0), messages are no longer picked up from the queues when running on a windows 2008 server. Everything works as expected on my dev machine (win 7). Messages are successfully put on the queues, but then nothing happens.

Could this be a permissions issue? If so, I would expect an exception, or at the very least a log entry, but there's no indication that something is wrong.
`loadFromRemoteSources enabled=true`
and
`<startup>

<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>

</startup>`
has been added to the config, and I've also tried
`useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"`
but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it had something to do with the server not being R2. After upgrading to R2, everything works as expected

Answer (score 0):

So nothing shows up in your logs or anything, the messages just sit on the queue?

Comment: Yup, exactly. No indication that anything's wrong, the messages just sit there